# array_shift function is not working properly in php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am having some trouble I have `$currentPages` variable which store below data

```
Array ( [1] => CMS_Content_Item_Page Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => Soft Snacks [headline] => Soft Snacks [image] => /ImageUploaded/4page-img1.png [description] => Cheese Burger.................................................................3500 Frw Beef Burger.....................................................................3000 Frw Eggs Burger.....................................................................3500 Frw [content] => Cheese Burger.................................................................3500 Frw Beef Burger.....................................................................3000 Frw Eggs Burger.....................................................................3500 Frw Meat Ball ( 3 ) ................................................................1500 Frw Chicken wings.................................................................4000 Frw Sambusa ( 3 ).................................................................1500 Frw Cheese Plate ..................................................................2500 Frw Cheese Sausage..............................................................3500 Frw [parent_id] => 0 [_namespace:protected] => restaurant [_restaurantModel:protected] => Application_Model_Restaurant Object ( [_name:protected] => restaurants [_dependentTables:protected] => Array ( [0] => Application_Model_ContentNode ) [_referenceMap:protected] => Array ( [Restaurant] => Array ( [columns] => Array ( [0] => parent_id ) [refTableClass] => Application_Model_Restaurant [refColumns] => Array ( [0] => id ) [onDelete] => cascade [onUpdate] => restrict ) ) [_definition:protected] => [_definitionConfigName:protected] => [_db:protected] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql Object ( [_pdoType:protected] => mysql [_numericDataTypes:protected] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [INT] => 0 [INTEGER] => 0 [MEDIUMINT] => 0 [SMALLINT] => 0 [TINYINT] => 0 [BIGINT] => 1 [SERIAL] => 1 [DEC] => 2 [DECIMAL] => 2 [DOUBLE] => 2 [DOUBLE PRECISION] => 2 [FIXED] => 2 [FLOAT] => 2 ) [_defaultStmtClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo [_config:protected] => Array ( [host] => localhost [username] => hotelrwanda [password] => password [dbname] => hotelrwanda_db [charset] => [persistent] => [options] => Array ( [caseFolding] => 0 [autoQuoteIdentifiers] => 1 [fetchMode] => 2 ) [driver_options] => Array ( ) ) [_fetchMode:protected] => 2 [_profiler:protected] => Zend_Db_Profiler Object ( [_queryProfiles:protected] => Array ( ) [_enabled:protected] => [_filterElapsedSecs:protected] => [_filterTypes:protected] => ) [_defaultProfilerClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Profiler [_connection:protected] => PDO Object ( ) [_caseFolding:protected] => 0 [_autoQuoteIdentifiers:protected] => 1 [_allowSerialization:protected] => 1 [_autoReconnectOnUnserialize:protected] => ) [_schema:protected] => [_cols:protected] => Array ( [0] => id [1] => parent_id [2] => namespace [3] => name [4] => date_created ) [_primary:protected] => Array ( [1] => id ) [_identity:protected] => 1 [_sequence:protected] => 1 [_metadata:protected] => Array ( [id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => restaurants [COLUMN_NAME] => id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 1 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => 1 [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 1 [IDENTITY] => 1 ) [parent_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => restaurants [COLUMN_NAME] => parent_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 2 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [namespace] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => restaurants [COLUMN_NAME] => namespace [COLUMN_POSITION] => 3 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 50 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [name] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => restaurants [COLUMN_NAME] => name [COLUMN_POSITION] => 4 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 100 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [date_created] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => restaurants [COLUMN_NAME] => date_created [COLUMN_POSITION] => 5 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) ) [_metadataCache:protected] => [_metadataCacheInClass:protected] => 1 [_rowClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Table_Row [_rowsetClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Table_Rowset [_defaultSource:protected] => defaultNone [_defaultValues:protected] => Array ( ) ) ) )
```

And after using array_shift function it is giving me just Array ( ) which is nothing, is there any other option which can help to deal with this data.

[EDIT] Basically, I am using the zend framework here is the script which dealing with this array()

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $mdlPagepageModel = new Application_Model_Restaurant();
    $recentPages = $mdlPagepageModel->getRecentRestaurants();
    if (is_array($recentPages)) {
        // the 3 most recent items are the featured items
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i ++) {
            if (count($recentPages) > 0) {
                $featuredItems[] = array_shift($recentPages);
            }
        }
        $this->view->featuredItems = $featuredItems;

        if (count($recentPages) > 0) {

            $this->view->recentPages = $recentPages;
        } else {
            $this->view->recentPages = $null;
        }
    } else{
        throw new Zend_Exception("Currently, menu does't have any file!");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why is everything on a single line? How on earth are you going to debug that? Or how are you expecting us to do so?

Comment: I really hope this is a localhost deployment since you just posted your database name, db username, and password.  [username] => hotelrwanda [password] => password [dbname] => hotelrwanda_db

Comment: hahaha, yes this is just example,

Comment: It is considered good practice to make your code readable when asking for help.

Comment: The best info you can give us is what exactly are you trying to do? array_shift deletes the first element of an array, is this what you are trying to do? which element are you trying to delete? if you're not trying to delete an element, are you just trying to organize the array? how & why?

Comment: Yes, actually I want to organize it I don't want to delete it

Comment: well array_shift it wrong to use then. Explain how you want it organized and I'll try to help - also redo the var_dump you have at the top of your post, and copy the array from the source code, to keep its formatting, PLEASE..thank you

Comment: Hi guys, I got fixed it, I just create another object with the same data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the entire array is the first element of the array (the object), using array_shift is deleting that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe I'm reading his dump wrong.. but `array_shift(array(1 => $obj)));` returns `$obj`.

Comment: In the dump he gave, (posted into a code editor) the first object of the array is the only object, everything else is under that first key. If he uses array_shift of the dump he gave, it will just delete the entire thing.

Comment: Ahhh, I assumed Akram was dumping the result of `array_shift()`, not the original array.

Comment: All I'm saying is if he uses array_shift on the var which holds the above array ($currentPages), he will get an empty result. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @techjunkie.css I think he is right. it is making it empty let me post the function which is generating this array.

Comment: I found it difficult to count the loops manually; I suspect that you're correct and that array_shift is removing the only element of a very complex multidimensional array.

Comment: Hi guys, I got fixed it, I just create another object with the same data